# YouTubePlayerFragment plays sound but no video

Tags: android, audio, video, android-youtube-api

I am trying to reproduce a video on API 24 with a YouTubePlayerFragment within a LinearLayout, but, here is the thing:
 - When the Activity opens, YouTubePlayerFragment is not visible.
 - After the user click in a button (play button) YouTubePlayerFragment is set as visible and begins to play the video, but, only plays sound, I can only see a black rectangle with the YouTube controls.
 - If the user opens another activity and come back to the activity that contains the YouTubePlayerFragment, the video is reproduced properly, audio and sound.

The code that I used is the same that is showed in may examples arround the web, but, I follow these instructions: http://android-er.blogspot.com.ar/2013/06/example-to-use-youtubeplayerfragment-of.html

Update 1: I tested in API 25 and I got the same behavior.

Update 2: Api 22 presents the same behaviour.

Comment: Is video playing on API level below 24?

Comment: I only tested on API level 24, because is the only device that I had available.

Comment: @Yupi in API 22 I got the same behavior.